Render svg mid-text in compiler output
I have a compiler for a small circuit description language that emits diagnostics
and also produces on demand svg diagrams representing the circuits. I am using an ad-hoc emacs mode to call the compiler from inside emacs and what I would like to do next is get the (potentially multiple) svgs embedded in the compiler's output to be rendered in the buffer.
Sample output:
not is defined.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.43.0 (0)
 -->
<!-- Title: whitebox Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="126pt" height="334pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 126.00 334.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 330)">
<title>whitebox</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-330 122,-330 122,4 -4,4"/>
<g id="clust1" class="cluster">
<title>cluster_circuit__</title>
</g>
<!-- GATE_not_3__INPUTS -->
<g id="node1" class="node">
<title>GATE_not_3__INPUTS</title>
<text text-anchor="start" x="54" y="-294" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="20.00">x</text>
</g>
<!-- COPY_3__1 -->
<g id="node3" class="node">
<title>COPY_3__1</title>
<polygon fill="skyblue" stroke="transparent" points="65,-221 55,-221 55,-214 65,-214 65,-221"/>
</g>
<!-- GATE_not_3__INPUTS&#45;&gt;COPY_3__1 -->
<g id="edge4" class="edge">
<title>GATE_not_3__INPUTS:x&#45;&gt;COPY_3__1:n</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M60,-285.97C60,-271.07 60,-244.91 60,-222.5"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="62.5" y="-242.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> </text>
</g>
<!-- GATE_nand_3__0__0 -->
<g id="node2" class="node">
<title>GATE_nand_3__0__0</title>
<text text-anchor="start" x="41" y="-146.4" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="7.00">X</text>
<text text-anchor="start" x="73" y="-146.4" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="7.00">Y</text>
<text text-anchor="start" x="34" y="-120" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="20.00">nand</text>
<text text-anchor="start" x="41.5" y="-100.4" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="7.00">Z</text>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="24.5,-91 24.5,-159 93.5,-159 93.5,-91 24.5,-91"/>
</g>
<!-- GATE_not_3__OUTPUTS -->
<g id="node4" class="node">
<title>GATE_not_3__OUTPUTS</title>
</g>
<!-- GATE_nand_3__0__0&#45;&gt;GATE_not_3__OUTPUTS -->
<g id="edge3" class="edge">
<title>GATE_nand_3__0__0:s&#45;&gt;GATE_not_3__OUTPUTS:__VIRTUAL__2</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M44,-95C44,-69.17 44,-38.41 44,-25.36"/>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="45.75,-25.07 44,-20.07 42.25,-25.07 45.75,-25.07"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="46.5" y="-57.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> </text>
</g>
<!-- COPY_3__1&#45;&gt;GATE_nand_3__0__0 -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge">
<title>COPY_3__1:s&#45;&gt;GATE_nand_3__0__0:n</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M58,-214C58,-205.57 54.15,-204.16 52,-196 47.76,-179.87 44.68,-174.61 44.1,-160.25"/>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="45.84,-159.97 44,-155 42.35,-160.03 45.84,-159.97"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="54.5" y="-184.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> </text>
</g>
<!-- COPY_3__1&#45;&gt;GATE_nand_3__0__0 -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge">
<title>COPY_3__1:s&#45;&gt;GATE_nand_3__0__0:n</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M62,-214C62,-188.84 74.2,-182.72 75.82,-160.09"/>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="77.58,-160.06 76,-155 74.08,-159.94 77.58,-160.06"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="72.5" y="-184.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> </text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>

and is defined.


I got something that looks like horrible black magic to work
based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169931/emacs-narrow-by-regex
(defun render-svg ()
  "render svg inline"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((beginRegex "\<\?xml version=")
         (endRegex "\</svg\>")
         (beg)
         (end))
    (goto-char (point-min)) ;; go to the start of the buffer
    (if (re-search-forward beginRegex nil t nil)
        (setq beg (- (point) (length beginRegex))))
    (if (re-search-forward endRegex nil t nil)
        (setq end (point)))
    (if (and beg end (> end beg))
        (progn
          (narrow-to-region beg end)
          (goto-char beg)
          (insert-char ?\n)
          (image-mode)
          (image-toggle-display)
          (goto-char beg)
          (delete-char 1)
          (image-toggle-display)
          (widen))
      (message "did not find both instances of the regex, %s %s, no narrow" beg end))))

I don't understand why but if I just try to toggle the image
display I get an error telling me that emacs cannot figure out
the image format but if I insert & then delete a character before
doing so it's suddenly fine...
I am now trying to make this recursive to render all the svgs in the output.
